# CMS Options for Small Business

Tags: java, wordpress, web, content-management-system

I need some guidance in terms of the technology stack to choose for simple small business websites. I've had experience in .NET and Java for the back end. Occasionally worked with some Wordpress sites. I never did much development in PHP and so never was a big fan of Wordpress. But I always have people around me that want a website for their small business or just family and friends. At this point, I'm thinking do I just give into the who LAMP stack and start learning it as I don't see any open source good/easy solutions in Java and .Net or I should say that there are options but not sure if they can be a good replacement for 
Wordpress. Ideally I would like to keep developing in Java.

I already have so much on my plate that I want to learn and adding the LAMP stack just makes my goals even difficult.

Any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For most sites, you don't need to touch L, A or M.

What little PHP (if any) you'll need to set up a normal WP site for a small business, personal homepage, blog etc pp, I'm sure you won't have any trouble dealing with.

Almost all database interaction is (or should be...) done via WP's functions, so you don't even need to learn about MySQL's intricacies.

I say go for it. I've never liked PHP or WP either, but it's just so easy to get something running with WP, and it's very hacky, inviting you to build something that just works. I wouldn't choose WP if somebody asked me for a solution that he wishes to use continuously for the next 20 years, but honestly, most sites I see get relaunched every 3-5 years.

Plus the WP eco system is huge, there are lots of plugins (of variable quality, granted), so lots of things are already solved and just a few clicks away from being deployed in your site. And it's not made for developers but for users, so developers usually have no problem quickly getting things done.

Comment: You are right, guess I said that because sometimes if have to go do something custom in the site (It has come up a couple of times) I struggle with it and sometimes I will get stuff done but not sure if I did it the right way :-) Probably what I need to to do is just learn a bit more about just Wordpress. Also, couple of times people have asked me about small e-commerce site. This can be someone trying to sell some product from home. Again I guess PHP world has easy solutions?

Comment: Yeah, lots of costumizations can be done quickly, if you know a little bit about the filter / hook system WP uses (and the usual plugins). As for ecommerce: WP has WooCommerce to offer, which will give you a shop system that's easy to configure, easy to manage and looks just as shiny as Magento, Shopware etc pp. If you want quick, WP is what you want. If you want clean architecture, clean code, it might not be, because you really can tell that it has evolved during its lifetime.